# Is there a difference in image quality by rendering on different computers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have two computers. My new one is pretty solid, but it still takes 8 hours to render 3 seconds at 24 fps. I wouldn't mind it but i have other things i want to use that computer for in the meantime.

If i were to transfer the project to my old computer could i let it render non stop (for like a week)? Would it look any worse? I know it would take longer, but i don't really mind as long i can use my new computer without a major handicap.

I don't have the old one on me at the moment but from what i can remember it has

6gb of ram

core i3

nvidia gt 650m

EDIT: it's in cycles

Comment: It will do fine, just longer.

Comment: If amount of RAM is enough for the "old" computer to put there all geometry, textures and start rendering then it will work just fine

Comment: One thing you'll want to double check is that you have the same version of Blender on both computers. If you don't, you could get compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only thing that will change is the rendering time, everything else should be exactly the same.